# Justifying an entry in the table for $12$-fold way

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Showing the values in the first row hold is easy as we simply count various functions(injective, surjective, arbitrary).

Second row seems tougher. Here we cannot use the usual function counting techniques, so we'll use distributions of balls into boxes model. In the "injective distribution" case we distribute $k$ identical balls into $n$ numbered boxes. One possibility is to distribute the balls into the boxes $\{1, 2, 3, \ldots, k\}$. But this activity is identical to choosing $k$ boxes out of $n$ which is $\binom nk$ by definition.

I am having difficulty justifying the formula for distributing identical balls into different boxes in arbitrary manner (some boxes might get more than one ball, some get none). There does exist the famous technique of "Stars and Bars", but I get the feeling that this technique needs a justification of its own in the first place. Is there any way to justify the number/formula $\binom nk_M$ (where $M$ stands for "multiset" or "multichoose") besides "Stars and Bars"? If not, can we turn the "Stars and Bars" model into balls and boxes model? Thanks.

Comment: Stars and bars **is** a balls and boxes model: the stars are the balls, and the bars mark the spaces between adjacent boxes. Thus, `*||***|**` represents $4$ boxes; the first contains $1$ ball, the second none, the third $3$, and the fourth $2$.

Comment: Suppose we want to distribute seven apples to three people arbitrarily. Then the stars can stand for apples. But what if we also have pears and oranges?

Comment: All to be distributed arbitrarily? Then you compute the number of distributions of each kind of fruit separately and then multiply those results together.

Comment: What I am trying to see is this. Suppose I want to buy $15$ cans of soft drinks from a store that carries six types (with at least $15$ cans of each). How come in this case every can of soft drink is represented by stars? I mean all cans of one type are identical, but any two cans of any two types are different. Perhaps each box represents a type so that all cans of a type go to one box, but can't we simply place any can (of any type) in any box when distributing the cans into boxes?

Comment: Yes, for that problem each box would represent a type, and each star a can. The distribution of the $15$ stars in the $6$ boxes shows what selection of types was chosen. And yes, any can go into any box, since any can can be of any one of the $6$ types.